# Why can't JVP be measured in a standing or supine position?

Tags: cardiology, blood-pressure, venous-system

While carrying out the [jugular venous pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jugular_venous_pressure) (JVP) examination, the patient is kept at a 45 degree angle with respect to the ground. Why can't it be measured in a standing or supine position?